i tried running avatarify this issue keep coiming up
File "afy/cam_fomm.py", line 316, in 
out = predictor.predict(frame)
File "C:\Users\thebl\avatarify-python\afy\predictor_local.py", line 104, in predict
use_relative_jacobian=self.relative, adapt_movement_scale=self.adapt_movement_scale)
File "C:\Users\thebl\avatarify-python\afy\predictor_local.py", line 28, in normalize_kp
jacobian_diff = torch.matmul(kp_driving['jacobian'], torch.inverse(kp_driving_initial['jacobian']))
RuntimeError: CUDA error: operation not supported when calling cusparseCreate(handle)
i need help correcting it
